# Does acid anhydride give a positive iodoform test?

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds

I thought that acetic anhydride $\ce{CH3COOCOCH3}$  would give a positive Iodoform test because it has a $\ce{CH3-(CO)}-$ group.But it is given that this does not happen.

Is this true? If so, can anybody explain the reason? Thanks

Comment: The iodoform reaction requires enolate formation, which is not favourable for an anhydride.

Comment: The hydroxide in the iodoform reaction will hydrolyze acetic anhydride faster than enolization.

Comment: @user55119 Exactly, the iodoform test requires **aqueous** iodine which would clearly hydrolyse the anhydride to form the acid molecules before any enolisation would occur.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this source](https://people.chem.ucsb.edu/neuman/robert/orgchembyneuman.book/18%20EnolateIonsEnols/18Separates/18FullChaptOld.pdf), both acid halides and anhydrides can form enols reasonably readily and can be halogenated. I'd imagine, for anhydrides, this to be related to the potential for intramolecular hydrogen bonding in the enol form (as shown below):

[image]

This allows halogation at the alpha position by treatmeant with the halogen. I'd also imagine this process can be catalysed in *anhydrous* acidic conditions, avoiding hydrolysis.

The same cannot be said for base-facilitated enolate formation. As user55119 implied, the highly reactive $C=O$ is likely to be attacked *before* the alpha hydrogens (or even if deprotonation occurs first, proceed through an E1cB pathway due to the presence of a good leaving group; implied by Clayden Organic Chemistry), decomposing the anhydride instead of forming the enolate.

Enolate formation in basic conditions is usually required for multiple halogenation, and generally *three* substitutions are required to form a suitable leaving group for the haloform reaction to proceed. This is why it is a test for a *methyl* group next to a $C=O$ (as Mathew has said); as there are three alpha hydrogens.

Considering basic conditions are not an option, only mono-halogenation is feasible (perhaps even in acidic conditions) and the haloform test is made virtually impossible.

Answer (score 1):

**Note**: The anhydride would be hydrolysed first and would form acid which does not give the iodoform test.

---

Even if we consider that they were not hydrolysed , what would happen ?

[image]

$\ce{CH3COO-}$ would be removed and hence $\ce{CHI3}$ will not be formed.

Hence anhydrides will not respond to this test.

Comment: For formatting, See [here](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized) and [here](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here?noredirect=1&lq=1). For a more detailed MathJax guide, look [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), [minor other details](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3044/hidden-points-of-editing-you-probably-didnt-know?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Hydroxide will kick away $\ce{CH3CO2}^-$ group whenever possible, in this case, the very first step

Comment: https://web.chemdoodle.com/demos/2d-sketcher this allows you to draw compounds on the web and is a mechanism sketcher.

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi OP has specifically stated that this would not happen but rather this is a hypothetical "if it happens" scenario.

Comment: Yes. I am just trying to point out that there is no way the anhydride could give the test. Thanks @Safdar

Comment: I didnt say anything about it, also, the 4th step would prefer removing $\ce{CI3}$ and Iodoform will be formed

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi why would that happen? do you have conclusive proof?

Comment: @Safdar the point of the fake reaction is to make haloform which it completely fails too, counter question: Does the OP have a conclusive proof to eliminate $\ce{CH3CO2}^-$

Comment: In that case is there a reason to not attack the first carbonyl carbon which seems to be more preferable to me?

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi Yes I do have proof. Consider acetic acid and triiodomethane. Obviously acetic acid is the stronger acid. This means that the conjugate base of acetic acid which is acetate ion is weaker than the conjugate base of triiodomethane. Now, if that is true, the acetate ion will have a better leaving tendency. That is why it is eliminated. Also, please don't take the reaction pathway too seriously. There is a very minute chance of such a pathway even being followed when hydrolysis is possible.

Comment: my question was directed towards something else, i.e. why did OH not attack the first carbonyl, making a better base due to CI3 indictive effect, your mech mai not be taken seriously but shouldn't atleast be open ended

Answer (score -1):

Iodoform test is used to detect the carbonyl carbon and since acid anhydride is not a carbonyl compound , it does not give this test . The lone pair of oxygen ( the middle one ) and the π bond of carbonyl group are in resonance . When you actually  see the reaction mechanism , you observe that the methyl group attached to the carbonyl should have  acidic hydrogen but this is not so in the case of acid anhydride .

Comment: Keep in mind that Iodoform test is **not** used to detect a carbonyl carbon, but used to detect $\ce{CH3C(=O)-}$ group. Acetic anhydride has a $\ce{CH3C(=O)-}$ group and hence the question. Would you edit your answer accordingly?